# Is $S=\{-2+5x-2x^2, -6-3x+4x^2, -1-x+x^2\}$ a base of $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

let $V=\mathbb R [X]_{<3}$ be a vector space and 
$$S=\{-2+5x-2x^2, -6-3x+4x^2, -1-x+x^2\}$$
Is $S$ a base of $V$?
By intuition I would say no because the tuple is not of the form like $(x^2, x^1, x^0)$. 
But of course I would like to check it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to see if they are linear independent or not by the definition of linear independence:

Does
$$a(-2+5x-2x^2) + b(-6-3x+4x^2) + c(-1-x+x^2) = 0$$
only when $(a,b,c) = (0,0,0)$?

$$(-2a+4b+c)x^2 + (5a-3b-c)x + (-2a-6b-c) = 0$$
And we need this to be true for all $x$, which results in
$$-2a+4b+1=0$$
$$5a-3b-c=0$$
$$-2a-6b-c=0$$

Which arrives at the same question about the rank of the matrix in the other answer. But you could also try to solve to see if $(a,b,c)=(0,0,0)$ if you want.

Comment: I am even unable to solve that. Should I do it with an equation system containing $3$ equations? There are too many variables. Usually I am used to do that without polynomials..

Comment: @jublikon sure, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the matrix
$$M:=\begin{pmatrix}    -2& 5 & -2 \\  -6 & -3 & 4 \\   
-1 & -1 & 1 \\  \end{pmatrix}.$$
What is the rank of $M$? $S$ is a base for $V$ iff the rank of $M$ is $3$, that is iff the determinant of $M$ is different from zero.